# Show permissions of a folder using `ls`

Tags: command-line, directory, ls

A folder named `Dog` is within the working directory on my Linux system.
What is the shell command to list the access permissions of this folder?

I tried `ls -l Dog`, but the output is `total 0`.

Comment: @Ahhhhh I added the information from your comments to the question. For your next question, please add all this necessary information to your question from the beginning, then I'm sure it will be well received. This is a beginners question and as such valid and valuable.

Comment: Use `ls -ld Dog` to see the directory's permissions

Answer (score 7):

To obtain the access rights (and other information) on a *directory* (folder) using `ls` you will need to add both the `-l` *and* `-d` (`--directory`) options:

```
ls -ld Dog
```

Explanation, from `man ls`:

> ```
> -d, --directory
>        list directories themselves, not their contents
> ```

So if you omit the `-d`, then `ls` will report information about the directory's *contents*: in the case of an empty directory, the result will be something like

```
$ ls -l Dog
total 0
```

---

To get only the access rights, use `stat` rather than `ls` - either

```
stat -c %A Dog
```

for human-readable permissions, or

```
stat -c %a Dog
```

for an octal representation.

Comment: so does that mean to list the access permissions of the folder it would be ls -l Dog

Comment: @Ahhhhh no. `ls -l Dog` would list access permissions of files *contained in* `Dog` **if** there are any